# How to match all characters "*" using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have to create a regular expression to match all wildcards in my search string. Let say

> REGE*XPRESSIO*

There I have 2 wildcards "*". And with this regex:

> [*]{1,16}.*

I can match (16 chars max):

> *XPRESSIO*

But I only want to match :

> **

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to me that the answer is as laconic as : `\*`

Answer (score 1):

Since `*` is a meta-character, you need to escape it if you want to match it: `\*`. And then (you had the right idea here) you need to say "none or more" - which is `*`, so: `\**`, or maybe `(\*)*` depending on the precise syntax you have to use.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a reserved character in regular expressions. You can escape it with a backslash `\*`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `\*` is an answer

Check out this realtime regexp editor for real-time regexp check: http://rubular.com/r/gZLcKlw6Jc